# Get drive type with SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty

Tags: c++, winapi, usb

I would like to know whether i can get the drive information using the

SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA's DevicePath

my device path looks like below

"\?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_0111#5&39fe81e&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}"

also please tell me in the winapi they say "To determine whether a drive is a USB-type drive, call SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty  and specify the SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY property."

i too use SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty like below

```
while ( !SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty( hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,
    SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY,&DataT,( PBYTE )buffer,buffersize,&buffersize ))
```

but i dont know how can i get the drive type using the above..

Please help me up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for you will be find here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264203/en. Another link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305184/en can be also interesting for you.

**UPDATED**: Example from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264203/en shows you how to use to determine whether USB-Drive is removable. You can also use `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` with `SPDRP_REMOVAL_POLICY` on the device instance (use `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`, `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId` and then `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`). If returned `DWORD` has `CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_SURPRISE_REMOVAL` or `CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT_ORDERLY_REMOVAL` as value, the drive is removable.

Moreover the code example show how to open device handle which you can use with `DeviceIoControl` function to retrieve a lot of useful information which you can need. `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566997%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with different `QueryType` and `PropertyId` only one example. You can use `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` for example to receive storage volumes and their disk number.

If you will have full `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` information about your USB device we will be able to find all other information about it with different ways. One of the easiest is: just enumerate all drive letters with QueryDosDevice and query `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` for every drive. If you will find full match in `STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER` you will find the drive letter.

Comment: hi..
my input is devicepath can i be able to get the corresponding  drive letter

Answer (score 4):

I've created a `GetMountedVolumes` method with optional mask to specify what type of volumes should be included in the search (readable, writeable, removeable, hotplugable, eraseable).

I abstained from Setup API methods at all and only used null access volume handle for `DeviceIoControl` calls (no administrative privileges are required). I will share my code, may be this will help others to implement methods to determine drive (volume) type without using Setup API.

```
enum VolumesFlags {
    VolumeReadable = 1,
    VolumeWriteable = 2,
    VolumeEraseable = 4,
    VolumeRemoveable = 8,
    VolumeHotplugable = 16,
    VolumeMounted = 128
};

bool GetMountedVolumes(std::vector<std::wstring> &Volumes,
    unsigned int Flags = VolumeReadable | VolumeWriteable,
    unsigned int Mask = VolumeReadable | VolumeWriteable) {

    wchar_t Volume[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    wchar_t* VolumeEndPtr = Volume;

    Flags |= VolumeMounted;
    Mask |= VolumeMounted;
    Flags &= Mask;

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstVolume(Volume, sizeof(Volume) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            bool IsMatching = false;
            VolumeEndPtr = &Volume[wcslen(Volume) - 1];
            *VolumeEndPtr = L'\0';

            HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(Volume, 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
            if (hDevice != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {

                unsigned int CurrentFlags = 0;

                DWORD ReturnedSize;
                STORAGE_HOTPLUG_INFO Info = {0};

                if (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_HOTPLUG_INFO, 0, 0, &Info, sizeof(Info), &ReturnedSize, NULL)) {
                    if (Info.MediaRemovable) {
                        CurrentFlags |= VolumeRemoveable;
                    }
                    if (Info.DeviceHotplug) {
                        CurrentFlags |= VolumeHotplugable;
                    }
                }

                DWORD MediaTypeSize = sizeof(GET_MEDIA_TYPES);
                GET_MEDIA_TYPES* MediaType = (GET_MEDIA_TYPES*) new char[MediaTypeSize];

                while (DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_TYPES_EX, 0, 0, MediaType, MediaTypeSize, &ReturnedSize, NULL) == FALSE && GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
                    delete [] (char*) MediaType;
                    MediaTypeSize *= 2;
                    MediaType = (GET_MEDIA_TYPES*) new char[MediaTypeSize];
                }

                if (MediaType->MediaInfoCount > 0) {
                    DWORD Characteristics = 0;
                    // Supports: Disk, CD, DVD
                    if (MediaType->DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_DISK || MediaType->DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM || MediaType->DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_DVD) {
                        if (Info.MediaRemovable) {
                            Characteristics = MediaType->MediaInfo[0].DeviceSpecific.RemovableDiskInfo.MediaCharacteristics;
                        } else {
                            Characteristics = MediaType->MediaInfo[0].DeviceSpecific.DiskInfo.MediaCharacteristics;
                        }

                        if (Characteristics & MEDIA_CURRENTLY_MOUNTED) {
                            CurrentFlags |= VolumeMounted;
                        }
                        if (Characteristics & (MEDIA_READ_ONLY | MEDIA_READ_WRITE)) {
                            CurrentFlags |= VolumeReadable;
                        }
                        if (((Characteristics & MEDIA_READ_WRITE) != 0 || (Characteristics & MEDIA_WRITE_ONCE) != 0) && (Characteristics & MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECTED) == 0 && (Characteristics & MEDIA_READ_ONLY) == 0) {
                            CurrentFlags |= VolumeWriteable;
                        }
                        if (Characteristics & MEDIA_ERASEABLE) {
                            CurrentFlags |= VolumeEraseable;
                        }
                    }
                }

                delete [] (char*) MediaType;

                CloseHandle(hDevice);

                CurrentFlags &= Mask;

                if (CurrentFlags == Flags) {
                    *VolumeEndPtr = L'\\';                  
                    wchar_t VolumePaths[MAX_PATH] = {0};
                    if (GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName(Volume, VolumePaths, MAX_PATH, &ReturnedSize)) {
                        if (*VolumePaths) {
                            Volumes.push_back(VolumePaths);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } while (FindNextVolume(hFind, Volume, sizeof(Volume) / sizeof(wchar_t)));
        FindVolumeClose(hFind);
    }

    return Volumes.size() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your `Storage Device Path`:

- Open the device using `CreateFile`
- use `DeviceIOControl` to issue `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`
- this populates [`STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure
- which has a [`STORAGE_BUS_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) enumeration:

  ```
  STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR {
    DWORD            Version;
    DWORD            Size;
    BYTE             DeviceType;
    BYTE             DeviceTypeModifier;
    BOOLEAN          RemovableMedia;
    BOOLEAN          CommandQueueing;
    DWORD            VendorIdOffset;
    DWORD            ProductIdOffset;
    DWORD            ProductRevisionOffset;
    DWORD            SerialNumberOffset;
    STORAGE_BUS_TYPE BusType;         //<---------------
    DWORD            RawPropertiesLength;
    BYTE             RawDeviceProperties[1];
  ```

  }

The different *storage bus* types are

- **BusTypeScsi**: SCSI
- **BusTypeAtapi**: ATAPI
- **BusTypeAta**: ATA
- **BusType1394**: IEEE-1394
- **BusTypeSsa**: SSA
- **BusTypeFibre**: Fiber Channel
- **BusTypeUsb**: USB
- **BusTypeRAID**: RAID
- **BusTypeiSCSI**: iSCSI
- **BusTypeSas**: Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)
- **BusTypeSata**: SATA

So example psueudo-code

```
STORAGE_BUS_TYPE GetStorageDeviceBusType(String StorageDevicePath)
{
   /*
   Given a storage device path of

      \?\usb#vid_04f2&pid_0111#5&39fe81e&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}

   return its StorageBusType, e.g.:

      BusTypeUsb
   */

   //Open the disk for reading (must be an administrator)
   HANDLE diskHandle = CreateFile(StorageDevicePath, 
         GENERIC_READ,                        //desired access
         FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  //share mode
         null,                                //security attributes
         OPEN_EXISTING,                       //creation disposition
         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,               //flags and attributes
         0);           
   if (diskHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      RaiseLastWin32Error();

   try
   {
      BOOL res;
      DWORD bytesReturned;

      //Set up what we want to query from the drive
      STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY query= {};
      query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;
      query.PropertyID = StorageDeviceProperty;

      DWORD bufferSize;

      // Query for the header to get the required buffer size
      STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER header;
      res = DeviceIoControl(diskHandle, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
            ref query, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
            ref header, sizeof(STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER),
            out bytesReturned, null);
      if (!res) RaiseLastWin32Error();
      bufferSize = header.Size;

      //Allocate the buffer and query for the full property
      STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR *deviceDescriptor = GetMem(bufferSize);
      try
      {
         //Issue IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY to get STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR
         res = DeviceIoControl(diskHandle, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                    @query, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
                    deviceDescriptor, bufferSize,
                    out bytesReturned, null));
         if (!res) 
            RaiseLastWin32Error();

         return deviceDescriptor.BusType;
      }
      finally
      {
         FreeMem(deviceDescriptor);
      }
   }
   finally
   {  
      CloseHandle(diskHandle);
   }       

}
```