# How to determine what drives (volumes) show up in "Safely Remove Hardware" dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage, wdk

I have an application that watches for file system events. This requires a permanently open handle to the target volumes. This is fine for things like the system boot drive and other fixed devices but very undesirable if we're dealing with volumes hosted on removable devices such as eSATA, USB, Firewire, iSCSI, etc, as the user may want to unplug these at any time but the open handle will prevent "Safely Remove Hardware" from succeeding.

Ideally I'd like to prevent my application from latching onto any volume whose parent may appear in "Safely Remove Hardware" as the default. The problem is, there doesn't seem to be a documented way of determining what devices show up there and what devices don't. Am I missing something? Does anyone have a lead?

Note that it's possible to query a device's bus type and this almost gets the job done for me:

```
typedef enum _STORAGE_BUS_TYPE {
  BusTypeUnknown             = 0x00,
  BusTypeScsi                = 0x1,
  BusTypeAtapi               = 0x2,
  BusTypeAta                 = 0x3,
  BusType1394                = 0x4,
  BusTypeSsa                 = 0x5,
  BusTypeFibre               = 0x6,
  BusTypeUsb                 = 0x7,
  BusTypeRAID                = 0x8,
  BusTypeiScsi               = 0x9,
  BusTypeSas                 = 0xA,
  BusTypeSata                = 0xB,
  BusTypeSd                  = 0xC,
  BusTypeMmc                 = 0xD,
  BusTypeVirtual             = 0xE,
  BusTypeFileBackedVirtual   = 0xF,
  BusTypeMax                 = 0x10,
  BusTypeMaxReserved         = 0x7F 
} STORAGE_BUS_TYPE, *PSTORAGE_BUS_TYPE;
```

However the IOCTL returns BusTypeSata for both SATA and eSATA - yet the OS recognizes the latter as something that has to be shown in the "Safely Remove" dialog.

Comment: Whether a device shows up in "Safely Remove" does not depend on what device it is, but on the mount flags used to mount it. I am not sure on how Windows decides what flags to use, but that isn't my point. My point is that you should be able to enumerate the mount flags for the devices main mount point and check if the removable flag is set.

Comment: The [GetDriveType Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx) might get you started.

Comment: @margnus1 - GetDriveType will give me a subset of the info available in the above enumeration, and it definitely won't have a removable/fixed flag for esata/sata.

Comment: But regarding flags... you have nudged me towards SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty which appears to be able to provide things like "Removable", "EjectSupported", etc. This may be it!

Comment: And some further research shows that my question is actually a duplicate of this (not very aptly named) entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989713/get-drive-type-with-setupdigetdeviceregistryproperty

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for device events to know when you should close your handles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363217(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that you also need this for fixed devices as well, otherwise your open handle could prevent things like chkdsk from running (for that you need to listen for lock/dismount events).

-scott